# Error in include path?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I try to compile a program. But I think it don't work cause the include path is not right.

I use the power-linux-gcc from the ELDK.

The file structure is like this

```
linux-kernel ----- driver----graphic_test----- Makefile
               |                          |
               |                          | -- main.c
               |
                --  include--linux --- jiffies.h
                                    |
                                      -- semaphore.h
```

This is the way I include them in the semLib.c file

```
#include <jiffies.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
```

I also tried

```
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
```

I'm not quite sure if the problem is the include, but I think.

That is my Makefile:

```
CC=powerpc-linux-gcc

LIBS = ../../kernel/time/jiffies.o ../../kernel/semaphore.o #libdrmko.o libdrm.o libs3gko.o

INC =   -I../../include

C_SRC = main.c lstLib.c  systLib.c semLib.c    #taskLib.c

C_OBJ = main.o lstLib.o systLib.o semLib.o    # taskLib.o

graphics_test: $(LIBS) $(C_OBJ)
    $(CC) -o graphics_test $(LIBS) $(C_OBJ) $(INC)
```

That is the message from `make`

```
:~/Linux_Development_Workspace/linux-kernel/drivers/graphic_test$ make
powerpc-linux-gcc    -c -o ../../kernel/semaphore.o ../../kernel/semaphore.c
../../kernel/semaphore.c:28:28: error: linux/compiler.h: No such file or directory
../../kernel/semaphore.c:30:26: error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory
../../kernel/semaphore.c:32:29: error: linux/semaphore.h: No such file or directory
../../kernel/semaphore.c:33:28: error: linux/spinlock.h: No such file or directory
../../kernel/semaphore.c:34:26: error: linux/ftrace.h: No such file or directory
../../kernel/semaphore.c:36: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:37: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:38: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:39: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:40: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:53: warning: 'struct semaphore' declared inside parameter list
../../kernel/semaphore.c:53: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
../../kernel/semaphore.c: In function 'down':
../../kernel/semaphore.c:57: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:58: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:59: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c: At top level:
../../kernel/semaphore.c:64: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
../../kernel/semaphore.c:64: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../../kernel/semaphore.c:75: warning: 'struct semaphore' declared inside parameter list
../../kernel/semaphore.c: In function 'down_interruptible':
../../kernel/semaphore.c:80: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:81: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:82: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:85: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c: At top level:
../../kernel/semaphore.c:89: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
../../kernel/semaphore.c:89: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../../kernel/semaphore.c:101: warning: 'struct semaphore' declared inside parameter list
../../kernel/semaphore.c: In function 'down_killable':
../../kernel/semaphore.c:106: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:107: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:108: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:111: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c: At top level:
../../kernel/semaphore.c:115: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
../../kernel/semaphore.c:115: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../../kernel/semaphore.c:130: warning: 'struct semaphore' declared inside parameter list
../../kernel/semaphore.c: In function 'down_trylock':
../../kernel/semaphore.c:135: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:136: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:138: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:139: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c: At top level:
../../kernel/semaphore.c:143: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
../../kernel/semaphore.c:143: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../../kernel/semaphore.c:155: warning: 'struct semaphore' declared inside parameter list
../../kernel/semaphore.c: In function 'down_timeout':
../../kernel/semaphore.c:160: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:161: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:162: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:165: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c: At top level:
../../kernel/semaphore.c:169: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
../../kernel/semaphore.c:169: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../../kernel/semaphore.c:178: warning: 'struct semaphore' declared inside parameter list
../../kernel/semaphore.c: In function 'up':
../../kernel/semaphore.c:182: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:183: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:184: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:187: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c: At top level:
../../kernel/semaphore.c:189: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
../../kernel/semaphore.c:189: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../../kernel/semaphore.c:194: error: field 'list' has incomplete type
../../kernel/semaphore.c:204: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__down_common'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:236: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:241: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:246: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:251: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'
../../kernel/semaphore.c:256: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
make: *** [../../kernel/semaphore.o] Fehler 1
```

Comment: In the kernel source `jiffies.h` and `semaphore.h` are in the directory `include/linux/`. However, in your depiction they appear directly under `include/`... Is that right?

Comment: @pacha your right just a mistake in the post I edited it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You either need to add:

```
-I../../include/linux
```

to the command line, or you need to write:

```
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
```

to gain access to the file.  Check on other code using `jiffies.h` to see which is the standard style.

---

The other problem is that the individual file compilation is not getting the `-I` option:

```
powerpc-linux-gcc    -c -o ../../kernel/semaphore.o ../../kernel/semaphore.c
```

You need to know what the built-in rules for compiling a C file look like.  Ultimately, you need to get the `${INC}` value into `${CFLAGS}`.  Trivially, this might be:

```
CFLAGS = ${INC}
```

More typically (at least in my experience), CFLAGS is built from a number of macros.  OTOH, it doesn't look like that will be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you sure that I don't need both? I tried the possibility : only `#include <linux/jiffies.h>` and it didn't work

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, the second point you described was the crucial point. ( see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan describes the crucial point. (More or less) the problem is/was that the compiler try to compile/build semaphore.o and use for that the default include path. So I edited my makefile , you can see it below, what solved the problem.

```
CC=powerpc-linux-gcc

LIBS =  ../../kernel/semaphore.o  #libdrmko.o libdrm.o libs3gko.o #../../kernel/time/jiffies.o

INC  =  -I/home/linuxdev/Linux_Development_Workspace/linux-kernel/include/ 
INC +=  -I/home/linuxdev/Linux_Development_Workspace/linux-kernel/
INC +=  -I/home/linuxdev/Linux_Development_Workspace/linux-kernel/include/linux

KDIR =  /home/linuxdev/Linux_Development_Workspace/linux-kernel/

C_SRC = main.c lstLib.c  systLib.c semLib.c    #taskLib.c

C_OBJ = main.o lstLib.o systLib.o semLib.o    # taskLib.o

graphics_test: $(LIBS) $(C_OBJ)
    echo Halloq
    $(CC)  -o --sysroot=$(KDIR)  graphics_test   $(LIBS) $(C_OBJ)  #$(INC)

semaphore: semaphore.o
    $(CC)  -o --sysroot=$(KDIR) semaphore ../../kernel/semaphore.o

semaphore.o: 
    @echo pwd:  $(shell pwd)
    $(CC)  -c  $(INC) ../../kernel/semaphore.c
```

I think the way Jonathan described would also work, but I didn't try it!

Thanks all who tried to help me